# How to remove markers from DirectionsRenderer start and end point

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi i am using google map api for direction route in the javascript and i want to remove marker from start, end and waypoints.I allready try to suppressMarkers: true but it is not work for me. please give me quick  solution for it my javascript code look like this

```
var map;
  var directionDisplay;
  var directionsService;
  var stepDisplay;
  var markerArray = [];
  var position;
  var marker = null;
  var polyline = null;
  var poly2 = null;
  var speed = 10, wait = 1;
  var infowindow = null;
  var myPano;   
  var panoClient;
  var nextPanoId;
  var timerHandle = null;

function createMarker(latlng, label, html) {
// alert("createMarker("+latlng+","+label+","+html+","+color+")");
    var contentString = '<b>'+label+'</b><br>'+html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        title: label,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });
        marker.myname = label;
        // gmarkers.push(marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
    return marker;
}


function initialize() {
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
    { 
      size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
    });
    // Instantiate a directions service.
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    // Create a map and center it on Manhattan.
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    address = 'indore'
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
       map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    });

    // Create a renderer for directions and bind it to the map.
    var rendererOptions = {
      map: map
    }
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);

    // Instantiate an info window to hold step text.
    stepDisplay = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeWeight: 3
    });
    poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#CCCCCC',
    strokeWeight: 3
    });
  }



    var steps = []

function calcRoute(){
    if (timerHandle) { clearTimeout(timerHandle); }
    if (marker) {
        marker.setMap(null);
    }
    polyline.setMap(null);
    poly2.setMap(null);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
    polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: [],
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeWeight: 3
    });
    poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: [],
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeWeight: 3
    });
    // Create a renderer for directions and bind it to the map.
    var rendererOptions = {
      map: map
    }
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
    var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
    var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
    var travelMode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: travelMode,
        waypoints: [{location: 'Dhar, IN'}, {location: 'Mhow, IN'}],
    };

    // Route the directions and pass the response to a
    // function to create markers for each step.
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var route = response.routes[0];
            startLocation = new Object();
            endLocation = new Object();

            // For each route, display summary information.
            var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
            var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
            for (i=0;i<legs.length;i++) {
                if (i == 0) { 
                    startLocation.latlng = legs[i].start_location;
                    startLocation.address = legs[i].start_address;
                    // marker = google.maps.Marker({map:map,position: startLocation.latlng});
                    marker = createMarker(legs[i].start_location,"start",legs[i].start_address,"green");
                }
                endLocation.latlng = legs[i].end_location;
                endLocation.address = legs[i].end_address;
                var steps = legs[i].steps;
                for (j=0;j<steps.length;j++) {
                    var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
                    for (k=0;k<nextSegment.length;k++) {
                        polyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
                        bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);

                    }
                }
            }
            polyline.setMap(map);
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            //createMarker(endLocation.latlng,"end",endLocation.address,"red");
            map.setZoom(18);
            startAnimation();
        }                                                    
    });
}



      var step = 30000; // 5; // metres
      var tick = 100; // milliseconds
      var eol;
      var k=0;
      var stepnum=0;
      var speed = "120";
      var lastVertex = 1;


//=============== animation functions ======================
      function updatePoly(d) {
        // Spawn a new polyline every 20 vertices, because updating a 100-vertex poly is too slow
        if (poly2.getPath().getLength() > 20) {
          poly2=new google.maps.Polyline([polyline.getPath().getAt(lastVertex-1)]);
          // map.addOverlay(poly2)
        }

        if (polyline.GetIndexAtDistance(d) < lastVertex+2) {
           if (poly2.getPath().getLength()>1) {
             poly2.getPath().removeAt(poly2.getPath().getLength()-1)
           }
           poly2.getPath().insertAt(poly2.getPath().getLength(),polyline.GetPointAtDistance(d));
        } else {
          poly2.getPath().insertAt(poly2.getPath().getLength(),endLocation.latlng);
        }
      }


      function animate(d) {
// alert("animate("+d+")");
        if (d>eol) {
          map.panTo(endLocation.latlng);
          marker.setPosition(endLocation.latlng);
          return;
        }
        var p = polyline.GetPointAtDistance(d);
        map.panTo(p);
        marker.setPosition(p);
        updatePoly(d);
        timerHandle = setTimeout("animate("+(d+step)+")", tick);
      }


function startAnimation() {
        eol=polyline.Distance();
        map.setCenter(polyline.getPath().getAt(0));
        // map.addOverlay(new google.maps.Marker(polyline.getAt(0),G_START_ICON));
        // map.addOverlay(new GMarker(polyline.getVertex(polyline.getVertexCount()-1),G_END_ICON));
        // marker = new google.maps.Marker({location:polyline.getPath().getAt(0)} /* ,{icon:car} */);
        // map.addOverlay(marker);
        poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline({path: [polyline.getPath().getAt(0)], strokeColor:"#0000FF", strokeWeight:10});
        // map.addOverlay(poly2);
        setTimeout("animate(50)",2000);  // Allow time for the initial map display
}
```

Comment: How did you "try to suppressMarkers: true"?  [It works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ryp4ctnq/1/).

Comment: You have some typos in your code (`directionDisplay` != `directionsDisplay`) and are missing some dependencies (`Uncaught TypeError: polyline.Distance is not a function`).

Answer (score 3):

Pass the `suppressMarkers:true` option to the `DirectionsRenderer`.

```
// Create a renderer for directions and bind it to the map.
var rendererOptions = {
  map: map,
  suppressMarkers: true
}
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ryp4ctnq/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService;
var stepDisplay;
var markerArray = [];
var position;
var marker = null;
var polyline = null;
var poly2 = null;
var speed = 10,
  wait = 1;
var infowindow = null;
var myPano;
var panoClient;
var nextPanoId;
var timerHandle = null;

function createMarker(latlng, label, html) {
  var contentString = '<b>' + label + '</b><br>' + html;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    title: label,
    zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
  });
  marker.myname = label;

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  return marker;
}


function initialize() {
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
  });
  // Instantiate a directions service.
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

  // Create a map.
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  address = 'indore'
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
  });

  // Instantiate an info window to hold step text.
  stepDisplay = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeWeight: 3
  });
  poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#CCCCCC',
    strokeWeight: 3
  });

  calcRoute();
}

var steps = []

function calcRoute() {
  if (timerHandle) {
    clearTimeout(timerHandle);
  }
  if (marker) {
    marker.setMap(null);
  }
  polyline.setMap(null);
  poly2.setMap(null);
  if (directionsDisplay && directionsDisplay.setMap) {
    directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
  }
  polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeWeight: 3
  });
  poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeWeight: 3
  });
  // Create a renderer for directions and bind it to the map.
  var rendererOptions = {
    map: map,
    suppressMarkers: true
  }
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
  var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
  var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
  var travelMode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: travelMode,
    waypoints: [{
      location: 'Dhar, IN'
    }, {
      location: 'Mhow, IN'
    }],
  };

  // Route the directions and pass the response to a
  // function to create markers for each step.
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      var route = response.routes[0];
      startLocation = new Object();
      endLocation = new Object();

      // For each route, display summary information.
      var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
      var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
      for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
          startLocation.latlng = legs[i].start_location;
          startLocation.address = legs[i].start_address;
          marker = createMarker(legs[i].start_location, "start", legs[i].start_address, "green");
        }
        endLocation.latlng = legs[i].end_location;
        endLocation.address = legs[i].end_address;
        var steps = legs[i].steps;
        for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
          var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
          for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
            polyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
            bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);

          }
        }
      }
      polyline.setMap(map);
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
      map.setZoom(18);
      startAnimation();
    }
  });
}

var step = 30000; // 5; // metres
var tick = 100; // milliseconds
var eol;
var k = 0;
var stepnum = 0;
var speed = "120";
var lastVertex = 1;


//=============== animation functions ======================
function updatePoly(d) {
  // Spawn a new polyline every 20 vertices, because updating a 100-vertex poly is too slow
  if (poly2.getPath().getLength() > 20) {
    poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline([polyline.getPath().getAt(lastVertex - 1)]);
  }

  if (polyline.GetIndexAtDistance(d) < lastVertex + 2) {
    if (poly2.getPath().getLength() > 1) {
      poly2.getPath().removeAt(poly2.getPath().getLength() - 1)
    }
    poly2.getPath().insertAt(poly2.getPath().getLength(), polyline.GetPointAtDistance(d));
  } else {
    poly2.getPath().insertAt(poly2.getPath().getLength(), endLocation.latlng);
  }
}


function animate(d) {
  if (d > eol) {
    map.panTo(endLocation.latlng);
    marker.setPosition(endLocation.latlng);
    return;
  }
  var p = polyline.GetPointAtDistance(d);
  map.panTo(p);
  marker.setPosition(p);
  updatePoly(d);
  timerHandle = setTimeout("animate(" + (d + step) + ")", tick);
}


function startAnimation() {
  eol = polyline.Distance();
  map.setCenter(polyline.getPath().getAt(0));
  poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [polyline.getPath().getAt(0)],
    strokeColor: "#0000FF",
    strokeWeight: 10
  });
  setTimeout("animate(50)", 2000); // Allow time for the initial map display
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<input id="start" value="Indore" />
<input id="end" value="Khajrana" />
<input id="btn" onclick="calcRoute();" value="route" type="button" />
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is based on 
 In directionService  ... simply don't call createMarker function

```
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
             ......
             ......                
            for (i=0;i<legs.length;i++) {
                if (i == 0) { 
                    startLocation.latlng = legs[i].start_location;
                    startLocation.address = legs[i].start_address;
                    // marker = google.maps.Marker({map:map,position: startLocation.latlng});
                    //  
                    // comment like the row loke below
                    //marker = createMarker(legs[i].start_location,"start",legs[i].start_address,"green"); 
                }
```